# Every Derived Table must have it's own alias

Tags: mysql

Here is my `MySQL` Syntax:

```
SELECT f1.id
FROM
  (SELECT f1.id,
          count(*) AS c1
   FROM (friend AS f1
         JOIN friend AS f2 ON (f1.fid=f2.fid
                               AND f1.id!=f2.id
                               AND f2.id=12345
                               AND f1.id!=12345)))
WHERE c1>=
    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM friend AS f3
     WHERE f3.id=12345);
```

I can't seem to figure out where's the problem, I tried aliasing the inner result tables but they seem to return an error! I need guidelines.

Comment: Could you please post the error message?

Comment: Yeah, when I alias the result table used in the second from, it says **Unknown column f1.id (Third Line) in 'field list'**

Comment: That's a different error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of extraneous parenthesis and format your query a bit to have a cleaner look:

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM (SELECT f1.id,count(*) AS c1 
      FROM friend AS f1 
      JOIN friend AS f2
         ON  f1.fid=f2.fid AND 
             f1.id!=f2.id AND 
             f2.id=12345 AND 
             f1.id!=12345) AS t -- <-- Alias needed here!
WHERE c1>=(SELECT count(*) FROM friend as f3 WHERE f3.id=12345)
```

If you format like above, then you'll realize that the derived table of your query is missing an alias.

Also, the field selected by the outermost query, i.e. `id` should be prefixed using the alias of the derived table, i.e. `t`.

Comment: I did exactly what you said already, it shows an error message saying **Unknown column t.id in 'field list'**

Comment: Sorry! It worked, I was confusing the f1.id of the first and second line :)